# FancyBox2 compatible with IE7? Inline Content

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, fancybox, inline, fancybox-2

FancyBox does not open in IE7 on a site I am working on. Is this a coding mistake I made or does it not work in IE7?

Current Version of site:

http://arbiter-design.com/wycliffe/transformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the settings for your fancyboxes, you've left trailing commas, which IE is very picky about. Remove them and it will work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('area.fancy').fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 508,
        fitToView   : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        wrapCSS     : 'fancybox-custom', // < remove comma here
    });

    $('a.fancy').fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 508,
        fitToView   : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        wrapCSS     : 'fancybox-custom', // < remove comma here
    });
});
```

Also, because the settings are the same you can condense both those blocks into one by combining the selectors, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('area.fancy, a.fancy').fancybox({
        maxWidth    : 508,
        fitToView   : false,
        closeClick  : false,
        wrapCSS     : 'fancybox-custom'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Funny how simple things can break a lot of hard work.